# Why doesn't my user message stick to right despite setting "right : 0px";?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to put the user message on the right of the box, but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Here a small, easy reproducible example allowing you to appreciate the situation.

```css
/*** messages ***/ 
.messages_flow{ 
    grid-area: messages_flow; 
    width: 70%; 
    border: solid; 
    border-color: black;
    max-height: 10em; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction : column; 
    align-items: end; 
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;  
    padding: 10px; 
}

.user_message{ 
    right: 0px;
    border : solid; 
    border-color : grey;  
    max-width : 90%;  
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages_flow">
New message
  <div class="user_message">
   Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I would make the text fill the box from right to left, according to the fact that the text-box would be on the right. I think flexbox could help with this situation. But for the moment I even don't succeed to put the box on right, so my experiments are blocked at this step currently.

Comment: Right side aligned text: `text-align: right;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `align-self: flex-end;`

```
.user_message{ 
    right: 0px;
    border : solid; 
    border-color : grey;  
    max-width : 90%;  
    word-wrap: break-word;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `right` here you need to use `position: absolute`

```css
/*** messages ***/ 
.messages_flow{ 
    grid-area: messages_flow; 
    width: 70%; 
    border: solid; 
    border-color: black;
    max-height: 10em; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction : column; 
    align-items: end; 
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;  
    padding: 10px; 
    position: relative; // <---- to make your child div relative to this div
}

.user_message{ 
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    border : solid; 
    border-color : grey;  
    max-width : 90%;  
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages_flow">
New message
  <div class="user_message">
   Hello
  </div>
</div>
```